# What web analytics services that integrate directly with Google Cloud Storage are there?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, web-analytics

I'm looking for a service similar to [Qloudstat](https://qloudstat.com/) but with support for retrieving access log information from Google Cloud Storage.

I've seen Google's recommendation to do analytics work by importing log data into BigTable.  This seems like a powerful tool but I'm looking for something more on the click-some-buttons on the end of the spectrum, not the write-some-BigTable-QL end.

Comment: Maybe this isn't a good question for stackoverflow.  But the google-cloud-storage tag is here and there doesn't appear to be any related activity on serverfault.  If another stackexchange site would be more appropriate, pointers appreciated.